# AxMSTSCLib Logoff

Tags: c#, rdp, logoff

I'm currently developing a tool that uses remote desktop sessions using the RDP protocol. I'm able to connect and disconnect to a remote desktop but I want to add the logoff functionality to it. I've looked far and wide in the various documentation but have not been successful yet.

I'm currently using AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting because I'm not yet able to get it working with the regular AxMsRdpClient6 without the NotSafeForScripting (or with any other version for that matter). So the issue is probably that this doesn't support logoff and I have to use the AxMsRdpClient6 version, I suppose ...

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

A demo of the code I'm currently using can be found below

```
        AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting rdp = new AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting();
        host.Child = rdp;
        rdp.CreateControl();
        rdp.Server = serverName;
        rdp.UserName = username;
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
        IMsRdpClient10 client = (IMsRdpClient10)rdp.GetOcx();
        client.DesktopHeight = 750;
        client.DesktopWidth = 750;
        secured.ClearTextPassword = pwd;

        rdp.Connect();
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote at least have the decency to tell me why ...

Answer (score 1):

This is independent of the ActiveX control version you use actually - the control doesn't have a logoff method, because it isn't an action exposed by the RDP protocol (at least as far as I remember).

It *is* possible to remotely log off your RDP session, but you have to use the Win32 WTSLogoffSession function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383836(v=vs.85).aspx) to do it. Unfortunately that's a little painful to do from C# since you'd need to deal with PInvoke and marshalling structures in order to find the right session, but it should at least be possible.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've also found that option a while back but the issue with that solution is that the servers I'm connected to do not give me back the session ID when I use QWINSTA.